# How to remove all the settings for Outlook in macOS?

Tags: mac, microsoft-outlook

I install office preview on Mac, and Outlook just keep crashing every time I start.

So I uninstall office preview, reinstall the old Outlook for Mac that I had (which was working).

But when I start, it still crashes. So I assume it is caused by some setting changes I had from Office preview.

I tried removing `/Users/Mike/Library/Group Containers/UBF8T346H9.Office` but that does not help.

Is there anything I should do in order to clean unremove office (remove all my setting and stuff)?

Answer (score 0):

A broken Microsoft font cache can prevent Office apps playing nicely, you can use [Onyx](http://www.titanium.free.fr/onyx.html) to fix this for you.

If that doesn't help, here are the locations of files you need to remove Office from your system:

- `/Users/Mike/Library/Application Support/Microsoft/Office`
- `/Users/Mike/Library/Caches/Microsoft/Office`
- `/Users/Mike/Library/Preferences/ByHost/MicrosoftRegistrationDB.xxxxx`
- `/Users/Mike/Library/Preferences/[all items beginning with com.microsoft]`
- `/Library/Application Support/Microsoft/[all items except Silverlight if you want to keep it]`
- `/Library/Preferences/[all items beginning with com.microsoft]`
- `/Library/PrivilegedHelperTools/com.microsoft.office.licensing.helper`
- `/Applications/[all MS items you want to remove]`

That's it as far as I can remember, don't think there are any hidden nasties - but again, Onyx can help here by showing hidden items.